# Approach to partitioning a large MySQL InnoDB table

Tags: mysql, performance, partitioning

The I have a table which will receive 45-60 million rows of IOT type data a year.  The initial desire is to *never* delete data as we might use it for different types of "big data analysis".  Today this table needs to support our online application.  The app needs fast query times for data that is usually within the last 30 or 90 days.  So I was thinking that partitioning might be a good idea.

Our current thinking is to use an 'aging' column, called `partition_id` in this case.  Records within the last 30 days are partition_id = 0.  Records 31 days to 90 days are partition_id = 1 and everything else is in partition_id = 2.

All queries will 'know' which partition_id they want to use.  Within that, queries are always by sensor_id, badge_id, etc (see indexes) all the sensor_ids or badge_id within a group i.e. `sensor_id in ( 3, 15, 35, 100, 1024)` etc.

Here's the table definition

```
    CREATE TABLE 'device_messages' (
    'id' int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    'partition_id' tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    'customer_id' int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    'unix_timestamp' double(12, 2) NOT NULL,
    'timestamp' timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    'timezone_id' smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
    'event_date' date NOT NULL,
    'is_day_shift' tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
    'msg_id' tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
    'sensor_id' int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    'sensor_role_id' int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    'sensor_box_build_id' int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    'gateway_id' int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    'location_hierarchy_id' int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    'group_hierarchy_id' int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    'badge_id' int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    'is_badge_deleted' tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
    'user_id' int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    'is_user_deleted' tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
    'badge_battery' double unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    'scan_duration' int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    'reading_count' tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    'median_rssi_reading' tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
    'powerup_counter' int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    'tx_counter' int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    'activity_counter' int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    'still_counter' int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    'created_at' timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY ('id', 'partition_id', 'sensor_id', 'event_date'),
    KEY 'sensor_id_query_index' ('partition_id', 'sensor_id', 'event_date'),
    KEY 'badge_id_query_index' ('partition_id', 'badge_id', 'event_date'),
    KEY 'location_hierarchy_id_query_index' ('partition_id', 'location_hierarchy_id', 'event_date'),
    KEY 'group_hierarchy_id_query_index' ('partition_id', 'group_hierarchy_id', 'event_date')
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci
    PARTITION BY RANGE (partition_id)
    SUBPARTITION BY HASH (sensor_id)
    (PARTITION fresh VALUES LESS THAN (1)
    (SUBPARTITION f0 ENGINE = InnoDB,
    SUBPARTITION f1 ENGINE = InnoDB,
    SUBPARTITION f2 ENGINE = InnoDB,
    SUBPARTITION f3 ENGINE = InnoDB,
    SUBPARTITION f4 ENGINE = InnoDB,
    SUBPARTITION f5 ENGINE = InnoDB,
    SUBPARTITION f6 ENGINE = InnoDB,
    SUBPARTITION f7 ENGINE = InnoDB,
    SUBPARTITION f8 ENGINE = InnoDB,
    SUBPARTITION f9 ENGINE = InnoDB),
    PARTITION archive VALUES LESS THAN (2)
    (SUBPARTITION a0 ENGINE = InnoDB,
    SUBPARTITION a1 ENGINE = InnoDB,
    SUBPARTITION a2 ENGINE = InnoDB,
    SUBPARTITION a3 ENGINE = InnoDB,
    SUBPARTITION a4 ENGINE = InnoDB,
    SUBPARTITION a5 ENGINE = InnoDB,
    SUBPARTITION a6 ENGINE = InnoDB,
    SUBPARTITION a7 ENGINE = InnoDB,
    SUBPARTITION a8 ENGINE = InnoDB,
    SUBPARTITION a9 ENGINE = InnoDB),
    PARTITION deep_archive VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
    (SUBPARTITION C0 ENGINE = InnoDB,
    SUBPARTITION C1 ENGINE = InnoDB,
    SUBPARTITION C2 ENGINE = InnoDB,
    SUBPARTITION C3 ENGINE = InnoDB,
    SUBPARTITION C4 ENGINE = InnoDB,
    SUBPARTITION C5 ENGINE = InnoDB,
    SUBPARTITION C6 ENGINE = InnoDB,
    SUBPARTITION C7 ENGINE = InnoDB,
    SUBPARTITION C8 ENGINE = InnoDB,
    SUBPARTITION C9 ENGINE = InnoDB)) ;
```

This table definition is currently working with 16 million rows of data and queries seem to be fast.  However, I'm concerned about the long term sustainability of this implementation.  Plus I now see that we are doing a lot of churn on the partitions as we 'age' the records by updating the partition_id of 10s of thousands of records per week.

The queries will almost always be a variant of this:

```
    SELECT * FROM device_messages
    WHERE partition_id = 0
      AND 'event_date' BETWEEN '2019-08-07' AND '2019-08-13'
      AND 'sensor_id' in ( 3317, 3322, 3323, 3327, 3328, 3329, 3331, 3332, 3333, 3334, 3335, 3336, 3337, 3338, 3339, 3340, 3341, 3342 )
      ORDER BY 'unix_timestamp' asc
```

There could be as few as one sensor_id in the list but often will be several.

I've spent hours of time researching partitioning but haven't found an example or discussion of partitioning for exactly this use case.  Since, we're using the artificial aging column of `partition_id` in this way I also realize that I can't do any true manipulation of the partitions, so I think I'm losing at least some of the value of partitioning.

Advice on partitioning schemes or even alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us the `WHERE` clauses for typical queries.  They are the most important in judging the efficacy of Partitioning and Indexing.

Comment: My apologies for not showing an example query.  One is now attached.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`; what version of MySQL are you using?  I suspect it will list all the subpartitions -- so much for any advantage in having subpartitions.

Comment: Do `event_date` and `unix_timestamp` contain similar dates?  That is, could you get rid of one of them?

Comment: We are on version MySQL 5.6.10, it is actually an Amazon Aurora database.  The `event_date` column is the date portion of the unix_timestamp which is localized to the timezone the data originated from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PARTITIONing` is not a performance panacea.

Not deleting?  OK, the main use (`DROP PARTITION` is faster than `DELETE`) is not available.

Summary Tables is the answer to Data Warehouse performance problems.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

(Now I will read the Question in detail and any answers; maybe I will come back in have something to change.)

**Schema critique**

Since you anticipate millions of rows, shrinking datatypes is rather important.

`customer_id` is a 4-byte integer.  If you don't anticipate more than a few thousand, use a 2-byte `SMALLINT UNSIGNED`.  See also `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED`.  Ditto for all the other `INTs`.

`'unix_timestamp' double(12, 2)` is quite strange.  What's wrong with `TIMESTAMP(2)`, which would be smaller?

`'badge_battery' double` -- Excessive resolution?  `DOUBLE` is 8 bytes; `FLOAT` is 4 and has ~7 signficant digits.

Most columns are `NULLable`.  Are they really optional?  (`NULL` has a tiny overhead; use `NOT NULL` where practical.)

When rows age out of being "fresh", will you do a massive `UPDATE` to change that column?  Please consider the large impact that statement will have.  It is better to create new partitions and change the queries.  This works especially well if you have `AND some_date > some_column` and that column is `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(..))`.

I have yet to see a justification for `SUBPARTITIONing`.

**Non-partition**

Given that this is typical:

```
SELECT * FROM device_messages
WHERE partition_id = 0
  AND 'event_date' BETWEEN '2019-08-07' AND '2019-08-13'
  AND 'sensor_id' in ( 3317, 3322, 3323, 3327, 3328, 3329, 3331, 3332,
                       3333, 3334, 3335, 3336, 3337, 3338, 3339, 3340, 3341, 3342 )
  ORDER BY 'unix_timestamp' asc
```

I would suggest the following:

- No partitioning (and no `partition_key`)
- Toss `event_date`; use `unix_timestamp` instead
- Change the select as follows:

...

```
SELECT * FROM device_messages
WHERE `unix_timestamp` >= '2019-08-07'
  AND `unix_timestamp`  < '2019-08-07' + INTERVAL 1 WEEK
  AND sensor_id in ( 3317, 3322, 3323, 3327, 3328, 3329, 3331, 3332,
                     3333, 3334, 3335, 3336, 3337, 3338, 3339, 3340, 3341, 3342 )
  ORDER BY `unix_timestamp` asc
```

And add

```
INDEX(sensor_id, `unix_timestamp`)
```

The, I think the following will be the processing.  (Note: It may be worse than this in some older versions of MySQL/MariaDB.)

1. Drill down the BTree for the new index to [3317, '2019-08-07']
2. Scan forward (collecting rows into a temp) for the week
3. Repeate 1,2 for each other sensor_id.
4. Sort the temp table (to satisfy the `ORDER BY`).
5. Deliver result rows.

The key point here is that it reads only exactly the rows that need to be delivered (plus one extra row per sensor to realize the week is over).  Since this is a huge table, this is as good as it gets

The extra sort (cf Explain's "filesort") is necessary because there is no way to fetch the rows in `ORDER BY` order.

There is still another optimization...

In the above, the *index* was in order, but the *data* was not.  We can fix that as follows:

```
PRIMARY KEY(sensor_id, `unix_timestamp`, id),  -- (`id` adds uniqueness)
INDEX(id),   -- to keep AUTO_INCREMENT happy
```

(and skip my previous index suggestion)

This modification will become especially beneficial if the table becomes bigger than the buffer_pool.  This is because of the "clustering" provided by the revised PK.

**More Normalization**

I suspect that many of those ~30 columns are identical from row to row, especially for the same sensor (aka 'device'?).  If I am correct, then you 'should' remove those columns from this huge table and put them into another table, de-dupped.

This would save even more space than tweaking INTs, etc.

**Summary Table**

Again, using your query, let's discuss what summary table would be useful.  But first, I don't see what would be useful to summarize.  I would expect to see a `device_value FLOAT` or something like that.  I'll use that as a hypothetical example:

```
CREATE TABLE Summary (
        event_date DATE NOT NULL, -- reconstructed from `unix_timestamp`
        sensor_id ...,
        ct SMALLINT UNSIGNED,  -- number of readings for the day
        sum_value FLOAT NOT NULL,  -- SUM(device_value)
        sum2  -- if you need standard deviation
        min_value, etc   -- if you want those
        PRIMARY KEY(sensor_id, event_date)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Once a day:

```
INSERT INTO Summary (sensor_id, event_date, ct, sum_value, ...)
        SELECT sensor_id, DATE(`unix_timestamp`),
                          COUNT(*), SUM(device_value), ...
            FROM device_messages
            WHERE `unix_timestamp` >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
             AND `unix_timestamp`  < CURDATE()
           GROUP BY sensor_id;
```

(There are more robust ways; there are more timely ways; etc.)  Or you may want to summarize by hour instead of day.  In any case, you can get arbitrary date range by summing the sums from daily summaries.

```
 Average:  SUM(sum_value) / SUM(ct)
```

**Reduncancy?**

`unix_timestamp`, `timestamp`, `event_date`, `created_at` -- all have the "same" value and meaning??

A note on `DATE` -- it is almost always easier to pick apart a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` than to have an extra column, and especially than having both `DATE` and `TIME`.

Without a date column, checking for all readings for one day needs to look something like:

```
    WHERE `dt` >= '2019-08-07'
      AND `dt`  < '2019-08-07' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: Good advice on shrinking some of the int fields.  I've done that in a couple of places but not as aggressively as I could.  Didn't know the thing about NULL, almost all columns could be NOT NULL so I'll definitely make that change.

Comment: Based on my limited understanding of Partitioning I was going for the smallest partition sizes I could get.  I'd love to drop that extra complexity if it doesn't offer any benefits. Looking through your article is helping me rethink that...

Comment: @Astro269 - I gave you one link; here is one more pointed to partitioning:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint .

Comment: @Astro269 - I added a bunch more.

Comment: Thanks for all the info, you've given me lots to consider and experiment with.  I have already moved the highest redundancy fields into other tables and gained significant size savings from that.  I’m not sure there's more that could be moved out. But it's something worth checking into.

Comment: Also, to your comment about summary tables, they are definitely something we're starting to do with these big tables.  However, we still need the detailed data for certain reports, analytics in the 30 - 90 day time frame.  But summary tables are definitely coming soon for our application.

Comment: Ok, and here's our dirty little secret about why we keep the unix_timestamp as well as the regular timestamp and perhaps you'll have a better suggestion.  Due to some legacy issues that I have to live with our MySQL database is pegged to EST time.  These sensors are all over North America and I wanted to be able to access the original UTC timestamp number without converting from the EST timestamp fields the database is keeping.  I'd love a suggestion but that's probably outside of the scope of my original question.

Comment: @Astro269 - 2 timestamps:  I see your issue.  Hmmm...  Which one is event_date derived from?  (Simple questions like "what is a 'day'?" become difficult.)  Meanwhile, how many sensors are there?

Comment: event_date is derived from the unix_timestamp.  There are 4,500 sensors but that number is expected to explode if we're are successful as a company.

Comment: @Astro269 - "Success" --> huge increase in dataset size, `INSERT` traffic, etc.  You may need more help than I have given you so far.  Make drastic schema changes _now_; it will be harder when the table gets bigger.